# How to ON & OFF flash camera in services

Tags: android, service, camera

well i'm using service to On & OFF flash light of camera,it's working fine but my mobile camera app is crashing, i'm not able to release camera in service

```
Camera camera = Camera.open(); 
final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();       
          if (isFlashOn) 
          {
              Log.i("info", "torch is turned off!");

             Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Torch is turned off!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
             toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 100);
             toast.show();

            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(p);        

              //Set flag to false               
             isFlashOn = false;
            release=true;

          }
          //If Flag is set to false
          else 
          {
              Log.i("info", "torch is turned on!");

             Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Torch is turned on!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
              toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 100);
              toast.show();

              p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

             camera.setParameters(p);

            isFlashOn = true;
            release=false;

          }

        if (release == true) 
          {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
                  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open Camera safely so for that you have to check camera state before the directly open your camera.

```
private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
    boolean qOpened = false;

    try {
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        mCamera = Camera.open(id);
        qOpened = (mCamera != null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return qOpened;    
}

private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
    mPreview.setCamera(null);
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

[For Further Details about Camera](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html) check it out and adjust as per your needs.

Enjoy !!!

Comment: Enjoy.if is it okay then don't forget to accept and upvote :)

Comment: okay you can't up vote due to low reputation but you can accept it